# Error while performing linear regression using statsmodel

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, linear-regression, statsmodels

```
    temp=values(times,l1dl,l1il,llcl,llcs,branchl,dtlbl,dtlbs,itlbl,cycles)
    objects.append(temp)
    
class values:
    def __init__(self,timestamp,l1dl,l1il,llcl,llcs,branchl,dTLBl,dTLBs,iTLBl,cycles):
        self.timestamp=timestamp
        self.l1dl=l1dl
        self.l1il=l1il
        self.llcl=llcl
        self.llcs=llcs
        self.branchl=branchl
        self.dTLBl=dTLBl
        self.dTLBs=dTLBs
        self.iTLBl=iTLBl
      #  self.instrn=instrn
        self.cycles=cycles

    def as_dict(self):
        return{'timestamp':self.timestamp,'l1dl':self.l1dl,'l1il':self.l1il,'llcl':self.llcl,'llcs':self.llcs,'branchl':self.branchl,'dTLBl':self.dTLBl,'dTLBs':self.dTLBs,'iTLBl':self.iTLBl,'cycles':self.cycles}
        

    
df=pd.DataFrame([x.as_dict() for x in objects])

#print(df)
print(df.describe())



X=df[['l1dl','l1il','llcl','llcs','branchl','dTLBl','dTLBs','iTLBl']]
Y=df[['cycles']]


#with statsmodel
X1,Y1=np.array(X),np.array(Y)
*X1 = sm.add_constant(X1)*

#print(X1)
model = sm.OLS(Y1, X1)
results=model.fit()
print(results.summary())
```

I am trying to perform multiple linear regression on system performace counter using statsmodel instead of sklearn because in sklearn there is no option of report summary , i have to print all stats individually . But using  `result.summary()` i can get all statistics together .
I have parsed data from a .txt file into columns and all the data is is in `str` format .

when i perform
`X1,Y1=np.array(X),np.array(Y) X1 = sm.add_constant(X1)`  i get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'` .I think sm.add_constant(x) requires x to be of constant and not string . Can you please help me ?

Comment: you can just pass the dataframe for regression ```model = sm.OLS(Y, X)```

Comment: X and y need to be numeric not strings. If the strings have numeric values, then you can convert them with pandas. If strings are categorical variables, then it's easier to use the formula interface which will convert strings to some numeric coding or dummy variables.